# Page layouts through apex

Tags: apex

How could I query page layouts and its fields for the specified object?

Is it possible to query?

> Example : for account object : Account layout and field in the layout.

Comment: You have to use Metadata API to get the details. Check this SFSE thread to get more details http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/18221/how-do-you-get-current-page-layout-information-in-apex

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways:-

1. Using Metadata API:- You can get [page layouts](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_layouts.htm) by Metadata API by defining the Object and Page layout name in package.xml
2. Using Tooling API:- Tooling API has object named "[Layout](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_layout.htm)" which can be queried.

There is no way to query the Layouts by SOQL in Apex.