# Displaying list of page layouts in Visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, managed-package

My question is how to display a list of page layouts available for a specific object. In my case I have to display a list of page layouts in picklist in vf page so that user can select the page layout, to which a field will be inserted.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As mentioned in [following post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/18221/how-do-you-get-current-page-layout-information-in-apex?rq=1) page layouts are only available through the Metadata API. You will need a complex process to retrieve information you asked for. you can find the details in the linked post.

Comment: Layouts are now accessible via Apex. See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Metadata_Layout.htm. I don't know if this will provide all of what Prasad is looking for, but the question you've linked to no longer completely applies.

Comment: I could not managed to get all possible layouts from that class, it would be great and appreciated if someone can share an example.