# Can I call salesforce metadata api from apex code?

Tags: apex, approval-process, metadata-api, approval-step

We have a requirement were all customer orgs should get approval process.  So we are planing to create a post installation script and use salesforce meta data api to create a approval process.  Is my plan is right will I be able to call metadata API from within apex code ?

Thanks in adavance

Comment: Take a look at this topic: [Has anyone, ever, successfully invoked the Metadata API from within Apex?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1082/has-anyone-ever-successfully-invoked-the-metadata-api-from-within-apex)

Comment: This is a duplicate of the above answer, which references in one of its answers this library, https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi

Comment: it is unclear what you mean by "customer orgs", do you mean: "where all customer account records are part of an approval processs" or are you referring to the creation of a salesforce org for your customer/s?

Comment: I actually don't think this is a true duplicate. If you could perhaps clarify in your question title, "Can I call Salesforce metadata api from apex post install script?"

Answer (score 5):

**Calling Apex Metadata API from Post Install Script:** Actually calling the [metadata API](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) from an Apex Post Install script is going to be problematic, since in order to call the Metadata API (which is a web service) you need to setup a Remote Site setting the customer org to permit the outbound call (which ironically is back to Salesforce servers). While you can package Remote Site settings you probably don't want to include one for every possible Salesforce instance your package can be installed on.

**Alternative to Automating Post Install Task via Apex Metadata API.** If you want to call the Metadata API post install, i would recommend providing a short post install process, to add the appropriate remote site, then have the admin navigate to a Visualforce page which contains any required post install org configuration changes you want to automate. You could use the Package Configuration link (see package definition) for this perhaps.

Comment: Andrew do you mean we have to do the metadata api call from VF?

Comment: You can yes, though if you want to make a Batch Apex job you can also do this. Examples of both approaches are included in the library.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.  If i use VF then I need to use javascript to call metadata api or do you mean after admin creating the remote site setting we have to do the metadata call using the above mentioned apex code ?

Comment: You can call the Metadata Api from Apex via an Apex Visualforce apex controller without using JavaScript. If you are wanting to deploy Apex or Apex Trigger or retrieve information, you will need a JavaScript component (also included) to manipulate the Zip data the API uses in these case. Otherwise you can use purely Apex callouts to the Metadata API without JavaScript.