# How to delete list view from metadata?

Tags: apex, metadata-api

We have a requirement where we have to delete list views. So I thought we could do something like this (this is similar to the create example mentioned [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1082/has-anyone-ever-successfully-invoked-the-metadata-api-from-within-apex/2207#2207)):

```
HTTP h = new HTTP();
HTTPRequest req = new HTTPRequest();
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
req.setHeader('SOAPAction', 'create');

String b = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
b += '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">';
b += '<soapenv:Header>';
b += '<ns1:SessionHeader soapenv:mustUnderstand="0" xmlns:ns1="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">';
b += '<ns1:sessionId>' + UserInfo.getSessionId() + '</ns1:sessionId>';
b += '</ns1:SessionHeader>';
b += '</soapenv:Header>';
b += '<soapenv:Body>';
b += '<delete xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">';
b += '<metadata xsi:type="ns2:ListView" xmlns:ns2="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">';
b += '<fullName>customObject__c.listView2</fullName>';
b += '</metadata>';
b += '</delete>';
b += '</soapenv:Body>';
b += '</soapenv:Envelope>';

req.setBody(b);
req.setCompressed(false);
req.setEndpoint('https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/Soap/m/25.0');
HTTPResponse resp = h.send(req);
System.debug(resp.getBody());
```

Even though when I run this in dev console, it succeeds but the list view is not deleted. *listView2* is the name of the list view. Please advice on how to go about it. Thanks

Comment: How do you see them not deleted, in the gui or query ? (are they recycle bin subjected?)

Comment: In the UI, they still appear.. Also i checked the status of the async Id in the workbench and status had failed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've updated the [Metadata API Apex library](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) you referenced in your question, to include examples on creating and deleting List Views. In writing the example I discovered two things.

- Make sure it is not a personal list view these are not supported

> List views with the Visible only to me Restrict Visibility option are not accessible in Metadata API. Each of these list views is associated with a particular user.
>
> Ensure that you pass in your delete request the [FilterScope](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_listview.htm?SearchType=Stem&Highlight=ListView%7ClistViews#filterScope). You should not have to pass this for a delete request in my view, but it seems Salesforce requires it.
>
> The following is my create example...

```
    MetadataService.MetadataPort service = createService();     
    MetadataService.ListView listView = new MetadataService.ListView();
    listView.fullName = 'Test__c.MyListView';
    listView.label = 'My List View';
    listView.filterScope = 'Everything';
    listView.columns = new List<String> { 'NAME' };
    MetadataCreateJob.run(
        new List<MetadataCreateJob.Item> { new MetadataCreateJob.Item(listView) },
        new MetadataCreateJob.EmailNotificationMetadataAsyncCallback());
```

**NOTE:** Example uses the [MetadataCreateJob](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/blob/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataCreateJob.cls) utility class, described [here](http://andyinthecloud.com/2013/10/27/introduction-to-calling-the-metadata-api-from-apex/) (there are other options). This ensures that any errors are retrieved and communicated back (in the default case via email).

The following is my delete example...

```
    MetadataService.MetadataPort service = createService();     
    MetadataService.ListView listView = new MetadataService.ListView();
    listView.fullName = 'Test__c.MyListView';
    listView.filterScope = 'Everything';
    MetadataService.AsyncResult[] results = service.deleteMetadata(new List<MetadataService.Metadata> { listView });
```

In your case, if you want to stick with the raw XML approach, you should be able to replicate what is being done above by adding the **FilterScope** element at the same level as the **fullName**. If your still having issues run the examples above an review the XML output in the Debug logs to compare.

Comment: Note once Spring'14 arrives we have immediate versions of create and delete operations, meaning that it will become a lot easier to determine failures as they will be reported immediately and you will not have to implement polling approaches to retrieve error messages.

Comment: greased lightning!

Comment: Thanks Andrew. How would anyone know that we have to add the filterscope?? We actually had a task to delete ~35k list views from PROD and we didn't have the metadata class implemented there, so I thought I would run the above raw xml in dev console. But Since I couldn't get it running, I wrote a chrome extension to accomplish it. Anyways thank you very much.

Comment: Will award the bounty once it is enabled :)

Comment: Is it possible via HTTP request or only via SOAP call?