# Is it possible listView upsert using query

Tags: lightning-aura-components, soql, metadata-api

lightning:listView don't support changing list views, so I get listview name using SOQL in order to make custom list view changer.

It's success, so next, I want to make custom list view creater.

I thought there is some method to create list view using SOQL, but I couldn't find such a method.

Is it possible or there is no method to create list view other than use default way?

**SOQL to get list view data**

```
public static final String objectName = 'MyObject__c';
public static List<listView> getListViewInfo(String objectName){
    List<ListView> listViewInfo = 
    [SELECT Name, DeveloperName 
     FROM ListView 
     WHERE SObjectType =: objectName];
     return listViewInfo;
    }
```

Comment: You can create this via code using the metadata API. You would have to download one of the wsdl files, use the wsld to Apex generator to create a wrapper for it and use that to create a soap envelope with the request. Refer this link: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24543/create-a-list-view-filter-via-apex

Comment: need to download Metadata WSDL as static resource?

Answer (score 1):

`ListView` is a [read-only sObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_listview.htm#!) representing a metadata entity. To modify metadata, you must use the Metadata API.

There is an Apex wrapper, [`apex-mdapi`](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi), available from a third party.

Working with the Metadata API is not to be done too lightly in an active production org. Be aware that the running user *must* have enough permission to make changes to metadata in Setup to access the Metadata API at all. Granting these permissions to non-system administrator users requires opening large holes in your org's security infrastructure.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I just want to custom my lightning:listView as like default list view. If you know some method to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Creating or deleting of list views and
Modifying of the list view filter
is not supported in lightning:listView component, but I need them.
so I want to know how to make these function.
Using metadata seems have security problem, so I wonder if there are any other way.