# How to Update Logo of Managed Package App?

Tags: managed-package

I have, in past, released a Managed Package with an App with a custom Logo file (which is a Document record part of the managed package) . Today I've been trying to update the Logo in my Package Development org, and I was able to replace the Document image with newer Logo image. But when I install it in user org, the Old Logo still shows up.

Is there no way I can update Logo of my Packaged App to newer Logo image file and for all subscribers who have installed the app? Can someone share some knowledge on this?

Answer (score 2):

As of 4/1/2015, I do not believe there is a way to do this.

Plus, if you use the "Replace Document" feature on the Document, customers will not get the new logo at all when upgrading.

The best workaround I could come up with was to create a 2nd Document and assign it to the App.  New customers will get the new logo automatically on install.  Existing customers will get the new Document on package upgrade, but the App will still have the old logo.  They can however change the logo on the App manually.

I realize this is not ideal, but it was the best workaround I could come up with given the current state of the platform.

**EDIT**

If you really wanted to get tricky you might be able to schedule some Apex code to run on package installation that updates the CustomApp logo... It appears the only way to do this through the Metadata API.   Again, this does not seem to be natively supported by the platform, but others have figured out ways to make it happen:

- [Has anyone, ever, successfully invoked the Metadata API from within Apex?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1082/has-anyone-ever-successfully-invoked-the-metadata-api-from-within-apex/2207)

Your mileage may vary.  I did not go this route due to it being overly complicated and this being a "nice to have" vs mandatory for me.

Answer (score 0):

I did change the logo and installed it to user environment, its showing up there perfectly fine. 
And as far as i know, the users who installs the latest release will be able to see the new logo.

Comment: No it doesn't actually. It does install newer version when someone fresh installs the app, but it does not update the logo of a user who updates the package to newer version. At least that is what I've seen, someone could correct me if there is some official documentation to support this and someone happens to have a link to it, much appreciated :-) ...

Answer (score 0):

in later version of your package the logo will be updated..

Comment: Can you explain this a little more?