# Access Shared Activities Setting from Apex code

Tags: apex, metadata-api, activity-settings

I'm relative new to salesforce, and a want to know if it's a way to access to Activity Settings values from Apex code, as specified in [Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_activitiessettings.htm), I know it's not natively possible to call Metadata API from Apex, and I'm not interested in implementing some third party lib.

Is there another way to accomplish this? I want to access `allowUsersToRelateMultipleContactsToTasksAndEvents` setting **without Metadata API**.

Comment: Miguel -- BTW, it is possible to access Metadata API from Apex - you use the [Apex MetaData API Wrapper](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Has anyone, ever, successfully invoked the Metadata API from within Apex?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1082/has-anyone-ever-successfully-invoked-the-metadata-api-from-within-apex)

Comment: No way, if you take a look I want a way to access Activity Settings without Metadata API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this particular setting, you can get it without touching the `Metadata API`:

```
Boolean isEnabled = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().containsKey('TaskWhoRelation'));
```

From the `TaskWhoRelation` [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_taskwhorelation.htm) (emphasis mine):

> ### TaskWhoRelation
>
> Represents the relationship between a task and a lead or contacts. This object is available in API version 29.0 and later.
>   This derived object is a filtered version of the TaskRelation object; that is, IsParent is true and IsWhat is false. It doesn’t represent relationships to accounts, opportunities, or other objects.
>
> TaskWhoRelation allows a variable number of relationships: one lead or up to 50 contacts. **Available only if you’ve enabled Shared Activities for your organization.**