# How to access workflows in APEX Class via Describe Method or API?

Tags: workflow

1)How can we access Workflows in apex classes? Using describe method I am able to access sObject but not workflows. Is there any way to fetch schema of workflow.

2) can we access workflow using describe method?

Comment: See this question: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1614/how-to-search-workflow-rules-or-validation-rules-etc-in-apex-i-e-metadata-searc/2208#2208

Answer (score 2):

You can not access workflows in Apex class using built in apex methods as it is itself a part of automation or we can say business rule. 
Also workflows don't require user interaction to proceed so they don't have significance of being available in normal Apex scenarios.

Instead Metadata API is the only solution why  which you can access workflow or any business logic or automation component to configure.
Metadadata API comes as WSDL so it is accessible through any language thats why Apex also works with it.